# Log file reviewing tools

Tags: logging, error-logging

I find myself regularly looking at log files my code generates, can anyone suggest any good (free) utilities for reviewing large log files? I've been using notepad++ up to now but I was wondering if there are any better tools?

Comment: What kind of logs do you get? Something that Apache generates ( [Common Log Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format))?

Comment: No, this is an in-house verbose text log format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very happy with [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/). It comes in a free and a pro version. The pro version is $35 well spent  i my opinion (it gives you search/filtering supporting regex).

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information on what logs you're using. You say these are in-house logs ... what is the structure of the logs? Would AWK/SED/GREP work for what you need? What platform are you on?

I write my logs out as XML and then I have a page in my webapp that reads the XML files and parses the structure into an accordion panel that I can quickly glance through to find the log information I'm looking for. A little consideration on both ends of that process and I ended up with a readily available logger that runs fast, keeps things local to the process, and which I can review at a moment's notice. No digging necessary.

Just depends on the problem you're trying to solve, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Log Monitor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/LogMonitor.aspx) for "real-time" logging updates. It doesn't touch grep for digging into specifics, but for a view of what's going on as time passes, it is perfect (no more file refreshing to get to latest entries).